# doxygen+sphinx(breathe) for documentation

Tags: doxygen, python-sphinx, documentation-generation

I am new to doxygen and sphinx usage. I have a requirement to create documents which is
programmed in C language.
The idea is to generate xml files from doxygen for each file and then use breathe as a bridge to sphinx for creating html pages.
I am successful in generating the xml files and able to get the html pages as well.
However, I see that each html file contains all the file contents, rather than each html per file/directory.

```
ie. dir1 => file1.h and file1.c
    dir2 => file2.h and file2.c
```

Output:

```
file1.html => file1.xml & file2.xml
file2.html => file1.xml & file2.xml
```

Expected output

```
file1.html to contain file1.xml(both header the implementation)
file2.html for file2.xml
```

Here are the settings:
Doxyfile(doxygen)

```
GENERATE_XML = YES
```

conf.py(sphinx)

```
breathe_projects = { <dir1_name>: <xml_path>,
                    <dir2_name>: <xml_path> }
```

Could anybody help me in setting the right configuration to get the expected output please?

Comment: I am able to resolve the problem. For the requirement as described above, I created a doxygen configuration file per directory, which inturn generates separate index and respective xml files. With this approach, i am able to get the correct html files generated.

Comment: In which case it would be helpful to put that into an 'answer' so that this shows as a resolved question.

Answer (score 4):

For the above requirement, Doxyfile per directory should be created.
This will generate xml files based on Doxyfile

```
i.e. for the files
dir1 => file1.h and file1.c
dir2 => file2.h and file2.c

create
Doxyfile1 in dir1
Doxyfile2 in dir2
```

This generates separate index.xml files per directory.

In Sphinx configuration(conf.py), location to xml should be provided

```
i.e. breathe_projects = { <dir1_name>: <dir1/xml_path>,
                          <dir2_name>: <dir2/xml_path> }
```

With the above changes, separate html files - file1.html(with file1.h and file1.c) and
file2.html(with file2.h and file2.c) are generated.